# Are powers of the harmonic oscillator semiclassically exact?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, path-integral, propagator, semiclassical, integrable-systems

The [Duistermaat-Heckman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duistermaat%E2%80%93Heckman_formula) theorem, although too complex for me to completely grasp, states that [under some conditions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32635/), the partition function for a special class of Hamiltonians is semiclassically exact. The harmonic oscillator is exact and should be an element of this class - the problem is that I don't completely understand the theorem, therefore can't generalize it.

I would like to know if, for systems of the form

$$ H(q,p) = \left( \frac{q^2+p^2}{2} \right)^\gamma \, , \quad \gamma \in \mathbb{N} \, ,$$

the partition function is semiclassically exact, and if this exactness implies that the semiclassical propagator is also exact.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 types of partition functions:

1. A finite-dimensional integral $$Z~=~\int \!dq~dp ~\exp\left\{-\frac{i}{\hbar}H(q,p)\right\}$$ with some $U(1)$ circle action, which OP didn't specify. Here a (Wick-rotated/oscillatory) [Duistermaat-Heckman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duistermaat%E2%80%93Heckman_formula) applies.
2. A loop-space functional integral $$Z~=~\int_{q(0)=q(T)}\!{\cal D}q~{\cal D}p ~\exp\left\{\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^T\! dt(p\dot{q}-H(q,p))\right\},$$ where the Hamiltonian $H(q,p)$ has no explicit $t$-dependence. Niemi-Tirkkonen equivariant localization to constant loops works generically away from caustics, cf. Refs. 1-3.

References:

1. R.J. Szabo, [arXiv:hep-th/9608068](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9608068); section 4.6.
2. A.J. Niemi & O. Tirkkonen, [arXiv:hep-th/9206033](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9206033); eq. (28).
3. A.J. Niemi & O. Tirkkonen, [arXiv:hep-th/9301059](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9301059); eq. (3.23).

Comment: I'm still tying to read the cited references. Pretty tough job.