# When is the Path Integral exact?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral

Feynman's path integral is exactly solvable for quadratic Hamiltonians and the Coulomb potential. I recently heard without proof that there is a larger class of systems for which it is also exactly solvable, but I couldn't find any general statement. Is there a way to summarize what is needed for the path integral's exactness?

P.S.: I'm not talking about Quantum Field Theory.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32635/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/458282/2451 and links therein.

Comment: [Grosche & Steiner](https://www.amazon.com/dp/3540571353/ref=rdr_ext_tmb) have some exact ones, but they all rely on ingeniously mapping them to Gaussians--the SHO. Why would you be contrasting the Coulomb potential to the Hydrogen atom?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Absolutely right. Edited.